# Configuring symfony to send mail via Postfix

Tags: symfony, postfix-mta, phpdotenv

After installing Postfix on my Ubuntu server and getting my Symfony application running, I'm attempting to have the system send emails via Postfix. I tested it out in the terminal to make sure that it sends properly and it does, but I'm confused as to what the Symfony configurations are to have SwiftMailer send email through Postfix.

In the .env file, there is a `MAILER_URL` attribute. What do I input there? My hostname? One of the destinations? Something else entirely? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could either set it to `sendmail://localhost` or `smtp://localhost`. Here's the [configuration reference](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#configuration).

Comment: Not sure if you managed to do this, but for me, it was: `sendmail+smtp://default`

Comment: @TacoV How did you manage to find this solution ? It worked for me but I couldn't find more infos about this configuration meaning

Comment: I just combined ideas from the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#using-built-in-transports) until it worked. I do not fully understand the meaning.

Comment: `sendmail://default` worked for me.